# Can we proxy web web socket to multiple layers of proxy

Tags: sockets, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

We have server which is exposed for public access with below websocket endpoint for web socket connection:

```
location /websocket {
    proxy_pass https://clusteringress/wscluster;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

The above will proxy the web socket connection will forward the connection to K8 Custer service which will finally accept the web socket connection, this cluster is private and can be connected from above server only.

```
location /wscluster {
    proxy_pass http://service;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

ingress of K8:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ws
  labels:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-http-version: "1.1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
spec:
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.className }}
  rules:
    - host: serverhost
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: servicename
                port:
                  number: serverPort
            path: /wscluster(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
```

When client connect to the web socket it is disconnected.

client -> example.com/websocket -> cluster.com/wscluster -> service:port/service

Comment: Yes, this should be possible.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich, i have added ingress of k8, can you give further details if something is missing.